# finding determinants using properties

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem here dealing with matrix determinants.

Let $A$ and $B$ be $2\times2$ matrices, where $\det(A) = 2, \det(B) = 3$.

Find: $\det((2A)^{-1} B^2)$

So far I have a formula that says that $\det(kA) = k^n \det(A)$

i don't know if I'm right but we can deduce out of that:

2^2(2) = (8)^-1 = 2A
& i also know 
b^2 = 9

i don't know how to finish this problem

Comment: Don't write "$B^{2} = 9$", instead write it like this $|B^2| = 9$ or this $\det(B^2) = 9$. $B^{2} = 9$ doesn't make sense because $B^2$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix and $9$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint:
$$\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B) $$
$$\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(A)} $$

Answer (score 0):

Use the following properties of the determinant:

$$\operatorname{det}(A\cdot B)=\operatorname{det}(A)\operatorname{det}(B)$$
$$\operatorname{det}(A^{-1})=\operatorname{det}(A)^{-1}$$
$$\operatorname{det}(kA)=k^n\operatorname{det}(A)$$

So we have

$$\operatorname{det}((2A)^{-1}B^2)=\frac{1}{4\operatorname{det}(A)}\operatorname{det}(B)^2=\frac{9}{8}$$

Comment: ok now i understand better thank you